# How to check if there are duplicates words in a file

Tags: python

I need to return True if any duplicates in the file. This is what I have but is not correct.

```
def duplicate(filename):
    infile = open(filename)
    contents = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    words = contents.split()
    for word in words:
        if words.count(word) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

file contents

```
This is a file with a duplicate. Just one.
You may try to find another but you'll never see it.
```

Comment: Why isn't it correct? Did you debug to print the count of each word? What does that file actually contain?

Comment: You are only checking the first word.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning on the first word count. Don't return false until inspecting all words

```
for word in words:
    if words.count(word) > 1:
        return True
 return False
```

Also, you're not stripping punctuation, so `word!` would be unique from `word`

It's also more performant to use a `Counter` object

Plus, it's better to open a file like so

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split():
            ...
return False
```

Comment: I haven't learned counter yet. My code seems to only be checking the first word from the file. The file contains - This is a file with a duplicate. Just one.
You may try to find another but you'll never see it.

Comment: Basically, `words.count()` will internally loop over every word. With a counter, you only look at each word once, and store it in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Usually a dictionary is nice for this kind of task (I'd suggest using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but I don't think you're quite there yet).

Dictionaries are great for grouping data, since the keys are unique, and can be really useful for membership testing, since the speed of the test does not depend on the size of the dict. In this case, you can track the keys as words and the counts as values. Then return `False` on the first dupe, which it looks like you tried to do:

```py
def has_duplicate(filename):
    # create the dictionary here
    words = {}

    # it is best to use a with statement to open a file
    # that way you don't have to close it
    with open(filename) as infile:
        # you can iterate directly over the file
        for line in infile:
            for word in line.split():

                # if the word is in the dictionary
                # then you've seen it before and it's a duplicate
                if word in words:
                    return True

                # Otherwise, add it
                else:
                    words[word] = 1
    return False
```

This won't handle differences in capitalization or punctuation, as a caveat